# Why does printf pad an 8-bit char to 32-bits?

Tags: c++, c, types, printf

```
char byte = 0xff;
printf("%lu\n", sizeof(byte)) // Output is '1'
printf("%x\n", byte); // Output is 'ffffffff'
```

If the size of `byte` is only one byte, then why does `printf()` behave as if it is four bytes?

Comment: google "integer promotion"

Comment: Just got a link [Deep C: Integer Promotion](http://www.idryman.org/blog/2012/11/21/integer-promotion/) explain what I was saying. Its implementation dependent.

Comment: possible duplicate of [char is signed or unsigned by default](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054939/char-is-signed-or-unsigned-by-default)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Formally, your program exhibits undefined behavior: `%x` format specification expects an argument of type `unsigned int`, but you are passing an `int`, as explained below (hat tip @R). This is harmless in practice on modern two's-complement machines, since int and unsigned have compatible bit layouts. But again, technically, this is undefined behavior and it would be a good idea to fix it, as in `printf("%x\n", (unsigned)byte);`.

The rules for passing parameters to variadic functions state that all integral types smaller than int get promoted to int. Otherwise, how would `printf` know, upon seeing `%x`, whether to grab one byte or four bytes off the stack? From the standard:

> **5.2.2p7 :**
>   When there is no parameter for a given argument, the argument is passed in such a way that the receiving function can obtain the value of the argument by invoking va_arg`(18.10)...` If the argument has integral or enumeration type that is subject to the integral promotions`(4.5),` or a floating point type that is subject to the floating point promotion`(4.6),` the value of the argument is converted to the promoted type before the call.

This is how your `char` turns into an `int`. It's unspecified whether `char` is signed or unsigned, but apparently, on the platform you use it's a signed type. So it gets sign-extended when promoted to `int`. `0xff` is `(char)-1`, and `0xffffffff` is `(int)-1`.

Comment: Do you happen to have the Standard reference to those rules?

Comment: 5.2.2p7 When there is no parameter for a given argument, the argument is passed in such a way that the receiving function can obtain the value of the argument by invoking va_arg (18.10)... If the argument has integral or enumeration type that is subject to the integral promotions (4.5), or a floating point type that is subject to the floating point promotion (4.6), the value of the argument is converted to the promoted type before the call.

Comment: This answer is not correct. The issue is that the program is invoking UB by passing the wrong type/value to `printf`.

Comment: While this UB is "harmless" in the sense that it's not formatting your disk or making monkeys fly out of your nose, it's still harmful in the sense that it's printing the wrong value.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's due to `integer promotion`

A good blog post on this concept: http://www.idryman.org/blog/2012/11/21/integer-promotion/

Answer (score 2):

You have invoked Undefined Behavior by passing the wrong argument type to `printf`. The `%x` specifier requires an argument of type `unsigned int`, but you passed (due to default promotions) a signed `int`. This is *arguably* valid if the value of the signed `int` argument is non-negative, but on your system, plain `char` happens to be a signed type, so `byte` contains the result of applying an implementation-defined conversion to `0xff`; the usual result of this conversion is -1.

Answer (score 1):

A `char` is signed 8-bit. The `"%x\n"` format says to print an integer. So the value of `byte` is sign extended to an integer. Since a `char` of `0xff` is, in that context, an 8-bit value of `-1`, `printf` is just printing the hex integer value of a `-1`, which is `ffffffff`.

Comment: On this platform, plain `char` is a signed 8-bit quantity.  The C standard explicitly says that whether plain `char` is signed or unsigned is an implementation-defined detail.